# Attach File Function Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to use [attachfile ampscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) in conjunction with date personalization string. Please see below steps:

1: Data Extract Activity which exports the data from data extension with the file name **ContactDetails%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%.xlsx**

2: File Transfer Activity which puts it into the import folder.

3: I use the attach file function `%%=AttachFile('FTP','ContactDetails%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%.xlsx','ContactDetails%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%.xlsx')=%%`

However when I receive the email instead of attached file I get the same ampscript
%%=AttachFile('FTP','ContactDetails%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%.xlsx','ContactDetails%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%.xlsx')=%%

Please note that attach file function is enabled for the account. When I test the attach file as `%%=AttachFile('FTP','20180221_New_CRM_Unsubscribers_Extract.txt','ContactDetailsTest.txt')=%%`

I get the attachment successfully. Is there a way to use `%%Year%%-%%Month%%-%%Day%%` in attach file function.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
%%[

set @today = format(now(1),"yyyy-MM-dd")
set @fileName = concat("ContactDetails", @today, ".xslx")

AttachFile("FTP", @fileName, @fileName)

]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards are not supported in AMPScript. You will need to generate the filename using Date Time AMPScript functions.

- Now() to get the current system date and time
- DatePart() to get a specified part of a date. You will need DAY, MONTH and YEAR
- Concat() to construct the filename from 'ContactDetails', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY'..

Then use AttachFile() with the filename to attach the file.